# group and filter and array of objects using VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, filtering, grouping

I have the following table which contains some objects :

```
var data = [
    {
        "userRoleId": 1,
        "userId": 1,
        "roleId": 1,
        "organizationId": "ORG_01",
        "roleTitle": "Admin",
        "organizationTitle": "Organization 01",
        "startDate": "2017-11-15",
        "endDate": "2017-11-15",
        "automatic": false,
        "useDate": "2017-11-15"
    },
    {
        "userRoleId": 2,
        "userId": 1,
        "roleId": 2,
        "organizationId": "ORG_01",
        "roleTitle": "Agent",
        "organizationTitle": "Organization 01",
        "startDate": "2017-11-15",
        "endDate": "2017-11-15",
        "automatic": true,
        "useDate": "2017-11-15"
    },
    {
        "userRoleId": 4,
        "userId": 1,
        "roleId": 4,
        "organizationId": "ORG_02",
        "roleTitle": "Referent",
        "organizationTitle": "Organization 02",
        "startDate": "2017-11-15",
        "endDate": "2017-11-15",
        "automatic": true,
        "useDate": "2017-11-15"
    },
    {
        "userRoleId": 5,
        "userId": 1,
        "roleId": 2,
        "organizationId": "ORG_02",
        "roleTitle": "Agent",
        "organizationTitle": "Organization 02",
        "startDate": "2017-11-15",
        "endDate": "2017-11-15",
        "automatic": true,
        "useDate": "2017-11-15"
    }
];
```

What I want to do is to group these objects using the object property `"organizationId"` and `"organizationTitle"`, so what I tried is I grouped them using `"organizationId"` as following :

```
var filtered = data.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
    (accumulator[currentValue['organizationId']] = accumulator[currentValue['organizationId']] || []).push(currentValue);
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
```

This will generate an object with a key which has the value of each `"organizationId"` used for grouping, and the grouped data as it's value.

Then I want to create an object for each `"organizationId"` used for grouping which will have three properties: `id` which will have the value for `"organizationId"`, `title` which will have the value for `"organizationTitle"` and `roles` which is an array.

This array will contain objects for each grouped objects, this object will have two properties: `id` which will have the value for `"roleId"` and `title` which will have the value for `"roleTitle"`.

So the result should look like this:

```
[
    { 
        id: 'ORG_01',
        lib: 'Organization 01',
        roles: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 'Admin'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Agent'
            }
        ] 
    },
      { 
        id: 'ORG_02',
        lib: 'Organization 02',
        roles: [
            {
                id: 4,
                title: 'Referent'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Agent'
            }
        ] 
    }
]
```

So I did the following, which works and I get the expected result :

```
var organizations = [];

for(var i in filtered){
    var obj = {};
    obj.id = i;

    var roles = [];
    filtered[i].forEach(function(el){
        roles.push({'id' : el.roleId, 'lib': el.roleTitle})
        obj.lib = el.organizationTitle;
    });
    obj.roles = roles;
    organizations.push(obj);
}

console.log(organizations);
```

As you can see I used too much code for this, first I used the reduce function then a forEeach and inisde it another forEach.

Isn't there a simple way doing that using vanillaJS (ES5) with the minimun code possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to club all your information.

```js
var data = [ { "userRoleId": 1, "userId": 1, "roleId": 1, "organizationId": "ORG_01", "roleTitle": "Admin", "organizationTitle": "Organization 01", "startDate": "2017-11-15", "endDate": "2017-11-15", "automatic": false, "useDate": "2017-11-15" }, { "userRoleId":2, "userId": 1, "roleId": 2, "organizationId": "ORG_01", "roleTitle": "Agent", "organizationTitle": "Organization 01", "startDate": "2017-11-15", "endDate": "2017-11-15", "automatic": true, "useDate": "2017-11-15" }, { "userRoleId": 4, "userId": 1, "roleId":4, "organizationId": "ORG_02", "roleTitle": "Referent", "organizationTitle": "Organization 02", "startDate": "2017-11-15", "endDate": "2017-11-15", "automatic": true, "useDate": "2017-11-15" }, { "userRoleId": 5, "userId": 1, "roleId": 2, "organizationId":"ORG_02", "roleTitle": "Agent", "organizationTitle": "Organization 02", "startDate": "2017-11-15", "endDate": "2017-11-15", "automatic": true, "useDate": "2017-11-15" } ];

var result = data.reduce(function(r, o){
  r[o.organizationId] = r[o.organizationId] || {id : o.organizationId, lib : o.organizationTitle, roles : []};
  r[o.organizationId].roles.push({id : o.roleId, title: o.roleTitle});
  return r;
},{});
var output = Object.values(result);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks saved me a lot of bytes x-)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with one loop:

```
 const result = [], hash = {};

 for(const {roleTitle : role, organizationId : id, organizationTitle : title, userId} of data){
   const key = id+"#"+title;
   if(hash[key]){
     hash[key].roles.push({ id: userId, role });
   } else {
     result.push(hash[key] = {
        id, title, roles : [{ id : userId, role}]
     });
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 with single iteration:

```
const newData = data.reduce(
  (obj, { organizationId: id, organizationTitle: lib, roleId, roleTitle }) => {
    obj[id] = obj[id] || { id, lib, roles: [] };
    obj[id].roles.push({ id: roleId, title: roleTitle });
    return obj;
  }, {});
```